# How to retrieve video using volley library?

Tags: phpmyadmin, retrofit2, android-volley, okhttp

Can you give me any reference because I often try but i can't found it. If possible can you give me php and java file share if anyone is known about that.

I try to found in YouTube, google but not I found they give retrieve image but not give me how to retrieve video then I try chatgpt but those code is having lots of error so can you help me.